# Geb not working with chrome driver

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab("org.gebish:geb-core:0.9.0"),
  @Grab("org.gebish:geb-spock:0.9.0"),
  @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.33.0"),
  @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.33.0"),
  @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.26.0"),
  @Grab( group='org.spockframework', 
    module='spock-core', 
    version='0.3'
  ),
  @Grab(group='org.gebish', module='geb-implicit-assertions', version='0.9.0')
])
import geb.Browser
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*
import spock.lang.Specification
import geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator
import geb.navigator.factory.*
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
def browser = new Browser(driver: new ChromeDriver())    

browser.go "http://www.google.com/"

assert browser.title == "Google"

browser.$("input", name: "q").value("query")
```

When i try to run the above code i am getting the following error

```
WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at geb.navigator.factory.DefaultInnerNavigatorFactory.class$(DefaultInnerNavigatorFactory.groovy)
    at geb.navigator.factory.DefaultInnerNavigatorFactory.$get$$class$geb$navigator$NonEmptyNavigator(DefaultInnerNavigatorFactory.groovy)
    at geb.navigator.factory.DefaultInnerNavigatorFactory.createNavigator(DefaultInnerNavigatorFactory.groovy:40)
    at geb.navigator.factory.InnerNavigatorFactory$createNavigator.call(Unknown Source)
    at geb.navigator.factory.AbstractNavigatorFactory.createFromWebElements(AbstractNavigatorFactory.groovy:44)
    at geb.navigator.factory.NavigatorFactory$createFromWebElements.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at geb.navigator.factory.BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.getBase(BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.groovy:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1671)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3408)
    at geb.navigator.factory.AbstractNavigatorFactory.getProperty(AbstractNavigatorFactory.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at geb.content.NavigableSupport.getNavigator(NavigableSupport.groovy:39)
    at geb.content.NavigableSupport.$(NavigableSupport.groovy:96)
    at geb.content.NavigableSupport$$.call(Unknown Source)
    at geb.Page.$(Page.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:848)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:831)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:164)
    at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:837)
```

Any idea on this how to resolve it ???

Comment: How is this related to Grails?

Comment: Browser is opening up and text is not getting set into the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

To use Geb/Chrome you will have to configure it on Mac, download the Chrome Web Driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and move the chromedriver to usr/bin folder. Restart terminal and run your Geb test with Chrome driver and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

As stated [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html),The followings can be the reason for your Exception.

1. Class is not available in Java Classpath.
2. You might be running your program using jar command and class was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.
3. Any start-up script is overriding Classpath environment variable.
4. Because NoClassDefFoundError is a sub class of java.lang.LinkageError it can also come if one of it dependency like native library may not available.
5. Check for java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in your log file. NoClassDefFoundError due to failure of static initialization is quite common.
6. If you are working in J2EE environment than visibility of Class among multiple Classloaders can also cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, see examples and scenario section for detailed discussion.

Comment: NonEmptyNavigator class is part of geb-core:0.9.0. This jar file is added to class path. So NonEmptyNavigator class should have been added to class path automatically.

Comment: It may not be available to JVM during Run time. Try to cover your code in try catch block so that we can spot what actually goes wrong.